# ¿Cómo evito que se abra la ventana modal al dar clic en un botón dentro de una tarjeta de bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Cuando doy clic sobre una tarjeta (de boostrap) se abre una ventana modal, y está bien, pero tengo un botón para eliminar en la misma tarjeta, y al dar clic se debe borrar la app, pero la borra y me abre la ventana modal con el siguiente elemento en la lista.

```
function eliminarApp(i,j) {
let cat = categorias [i];
let app = cat.aplicaciones;
app.splice(j, 1);
localStorage.setItem('categorias', JSON.stringify(categorias));
$('#appModal').modal('hide'); //Intenté hacer esto para evitar que se abra, pero no funcionó.
renderizarTodasApp();
}
```

Ejemplo visual:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente tengas que utilizar `event.stopPropagation()` desde la función que recibe `event`, evento del mouse, que está vinculada al botón de papelera.

Ej:

```html
<div onclick="console.log('d1')">
  d1
  <div onclick="console.log('d2'); event.stopPropagation()">
    d2
  </div>
</div>
```

Sin `event.stopPropagation()` si se clickea en d2 desplegaría

```
d2
d1
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).